# How to sum only one of repeated values from joined data in RDLC

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, sql-server-2019

I'm not sure if SSRS is dumb, or I am (I'm leaning towards both).

I have a dataset that (as a result of joins etc) has some columns with the same values duplicated across every row (fairly standard database stuff):

```
rid    cnt    bid   flg1   flg2
-------------------------------
4      2882   1     17     3
5      2784   1     17     3
6      1293   1     17     3
18     9288   2     4      9
20     762    2     4      9
```

Reporting based on `cnt` is straightforward enough.  I can also make a tablix that shows the following:

```
bid    flg1   flg2
------------------
1      17     3
2      4      9
```

(Where the tablix is grouped by `Fields!bid.Value` and the columns are just `Fields!flg1.Value` and `Fields!flg2.Value` respectively.)

What I can't figure out is how to display the sum of these values -- specifically I want to show that the sum of flg1 is 21 and the sum of flg2 is 12 -- *not* the sum of every row in the dataset (counting each value more than once).

(Note that I'm not looking for a sum of distinct values, as they may not be unique.  I want a sum of one value from each `bid` group, because it's from a table join so they will always have the same value.)

If possible, I'd also like to be able to do a similar calculation at the top level of the report (not in any tablix); although I'd settle for hiding the detail row if that's the only way.

Obviously, `Sum(Fields!flg1.Value)` isn't the answer, as this either returns 51 (if on the first row inside the group) or 59 (if outside it).
I also tried `Sum(Fields!flg1.Value, "bid")` but this wasn't considered a valid scope.
I also tried `Sum(First(Fields!flg1.Value, "bid"))` but apparently you're not allowed to sum first values for some weird reason (and may have had the same scope problem anyway).

Using `Sum(Max(Fields!flg1.Value, "bid"))` **does** work, but feels wrong.  Is there a better way to do this?

(Related: is there a good way to save the result of *that* calculation so that I can later also show a Sum of those totals without an even hairier expression?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic ways to do this.

1. Do what you have already done (`Sum(Max(Fields!flg1.Value, "bid"))`)
2. Sum the rendered values. To do this check the name of the cell containing the data you want (check it's properties) and then use something like `=SUM(ReportItems!flg1.Value)` where `flg1` is the name of the textbox, which is not necessarily always the same name as the field.

Comment: Interesting, `ReportItems` doesn't show up in the expression builder.